# Suggestions for a CAS to solve $\int^{\pi}_0\frac{4\sin^2\beta\cos^3\kappa}{(\sin^2\kappa + \sin^2\beta\cos^2\kappa)^2}d\kappa$

Tags: integration

I'm looking for a CAS that can solve the following integral:

$$\int^{\pi}_0\frac{4\sin^2\beta\cos^3\kappa}{(\sin^2\kappa + \sin^2\beta\cos^2\kappa)^2}d\kappa$$

I've tried Wolfram Alpha and it returns a very complicated result for the indefinite integral but is unable to produce a result for the definite integral.  I've also tried Sympy and it is not yielding anything (not sure if it is still running since it doesn't seem to provide any messages).

Does $\sin^2\beta$ cause problems for CAS even though the differential in the integration is stated as $d\kappa$?

Or maybe I just have to take the WA answer and work through inputting $\pi$ and $0$.  I thought I would ask here first since I have little to no experience with CAS.

Comment: If you have the indefinite integral and, differentiated, it reproduces the integrand, you can simply take the difference of its values (0,0) at both boundaries. Since by translation of $\pi/2$ the integrand is odd, the integral is zero.

Comment: WolframAlpha can do it with some extra coaxing, namely upon eliminating a factor of $\cos\kappa$ and adding the `Assumptions` to enforce a condition on $\beta$: see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5B%284+Sin%5Bb%5D%5E2%29%2F%28+++Cos%5Bk%5D+%28Tan%5Bk%5D%5E2+%2B+Sin%5Bb%5D%5E2%29%5E2%29%2C+%7Bk%2C+0%2C+%5C%5BPi%5D%2F2%7D%2C++++Assumptions+-%3E+0+%3C+b+%3C+%5C%5BPi%5D%2F2%5D). I cannot get it to work without resorting to WL syntax. The original, unaltered integral can also be done in Mathematica, but it takes it nearly $16$ times as long!

Comment: Thank you, but you have the limits of integration as $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.  If I change the limits to $0$ to $\pi$ the result is zero.  Am I missing something.

Comment: My mistake; the integral over $[0,\pi]$ is indeed zero, for the reason @RolandF mentioned. Upon translation, we have [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5B%284+Sin%5Bb%5D%5E2%29%2F%28Cos%5Bk%2B%5C%5BPi%5D%2F2%5D+%28Tan%5Bk%2B%5C%5BPi%5D%2F2%5D%5E2+%2B+Sin%5Bb%5D%5E2%29%5E2%29%2C+%7Bk%2C+-%5C%5BPi%5D%2F2%2C+%5C%5BPi%5D%2F2%7D%2C++++Assumptions+-%3E+0+%3C+b+%3C+%5C%5BPi%5D%2F2%5D) but $\cos\left(\kappa+\frac\pi2\right)=-\sin\kappa$ so the integrand becomes odd.

Comment: I've never used a Taylor expansion to try and solve integrals.  Would using something like that potentially change the result.  I am fairly certain that the result should be non zero based on the physics.

Comment: Well, the exact result is zero, so a Taylor approximation will likely also give you something near, if not exactly, zero. I think you should elaborate on your suspicion as to why it shouldn't be zero. What exactly is the origin of the integral?

Comment: *Mathematica* with the single command `Integrate[Cos[k]^3/(Sin[k]^2 + c Cos[k]^2)^2, {k, 0, Pi}, Assumptions -> 0 <= c <= 1]` immediately evaluates to $0$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\kappa\mapsto \pi-\kappa ,$ then $$
\begin{aligned}
I&=\int_\pi^0 \frac{4 \sin ^2 \beta \cos ^3(\pi-\kappa)}{\left(\sin ^2 \kappa +\sin ^2 \beta \cos ^2(\pi-\kappa)\right)^2}(-d \kappa) \\
& =-\int_0^\pi \frac{4 \sin ^2 \beta \cos ^3 \kappa}{\left(\sin ^2 \kappa +\sin ^2 \beta \cos ^2 \kappa\right)^2} d \kappa \\
& =-I \\
\therefore I&=0
\end{aligned}
$$